# How to execute python program made on IDE from command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I usually use pycharm for coding.
My question is how I can replace execution by IDE to command prompt execution. IDE makes it easy to set all python environments.

Windows 10 / Anaconda 3 / Python 3.7

My goal is to execute python program by windows scheduler.
Please let me know how to execute it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us an example code.

Comment: My question is how to set the env or libs which is used by IDE.

Comment: Ex. I'm using pandas however missing required dependencies.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Just open a command prompt, and then type:

```
python path_to_your_code/your_code.py
```

If this gives you errors that numpy, pandas etc are not installed then it means that the interpreter being used by your IDE (where you did not get such errors) is not the same one pointed at by `python` in command line.

If you're using a virtual environment or a python installation other than the default one you can just replace the `python` with a full path to the python binary in the environment you are using. So assuming your IDE is using the Anaconda environment, try this from command line:

```
c:\Anaconda3\python.exe path_to_your_code\your_code.py
```

Adding c:\Anaconda3 to PATH will not help if you already have another version of Python installed elsewhere, it will just mean that you now have two python.exe files in your path and `python` will still point at the same one.

However if `where python` already returns the path above, it means that your IDE is not using this interpreter and you'll need to find which one it is using. You can check this by looking in the Project Interpreter options or by running this script

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: It shows `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\your_code.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

Comment: That means the python install that is referenced from command line is not the one you're using from your IDE. If you type 'where python' in command line it will tell you what python you're using. You can go to 'interpreter' in the pycharm options to see which one is being used by Pycharm (if that's your IDE).

Comment: Sorry, just assumed you were using Pycharm, sure you can find the Python path in whatever IDE you use. If you say the path is the same that's very odd.

Comment: Actually I set the path to python as same as IDE settings. I had set path c:\Anaconda3\python.exe and I had set same path `set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Anaconda3\` on initial bat file.

Comment: That just adds that directory to PATH, it doesn't guarantee that any particular binary is used AFAIK.

Comment: I added directory to PATH. however I still have same error.

Comment: So when you run 'where python' does that return the anaconda path?

Comment: Are there any way to find which path is referenced by python as lib path?

Comment: And the IDE is also using that interpreter and not a venv? Pycharm's default option is to create a new venv for each project.

Comment: I have no idea what vend is. I might be using it. But what I should do to configure same environment?

Comment: It's actually virtualenv, not venv, my mistake. They are both ways of creating an isolated Python environment for your project. Check this help page for how to see what interpreter/environment you are using. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/project-interpreter.html

Comment: I understand what interpreter is. However my original question is how I execute program by command prompt.

Comment: I'm trying to help you verify that the IDE and the command line are pointing at the same interpreter because all the evidence suggests they aren't. If they were my original answer should just work.

Comment: It sounds I should not use Anaconda or IDE? Should I use original python better?

Comment: Using those things is fine, but if you installed your extra packages (pandas, numpy) into an environment created by those tools then you just need to find where that environment is and use that path on the command line instead of just 'python'.